# Serverless Error: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, serverless

when i type serverless deploy appear this error:
ServerlessError: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Answer (score 16):

I had to specify sls deploy `--aws-profile` in my `serverless deploy` commands like this:

**`sls deploy --aws-profile common`**

Answer (score 3):

Can you provide more information?

Make sure that you've got the correct credentials in `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials`. You can set these up by running `aws configure`. More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-quick-configuration

Also make sure that the IAM user in question has as an attached security policy that allows access to everything you need, such as CloudFormation.

Comment: there was all fine, seems there are a problem with windows,  i downloaded  another console: "ubuntu bash for windows" and install again nodejs, npm and serverless in that console, then i created a project and typed "serverless deploy"  and it work

Answer (score 3):

Create a new user in AWS (don't use the root key).

In the SSH keys for AWS CodeCommit, generate a new Access Key.

Copy the values and run this:

```
serverless config credentials --overwrite --provider aws --key bar --secret foo

sls deploy
```

[image]

Comment: works like a charm to me

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added region to the provider. I suppose it's not read from the credentials file.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: cn-northwest-1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was missing the `localstack` entry in the serverless file.
I had everything that should be inside it, but it was all inside `custom` (instead of `custom.localstack`).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, multiple credentials are stored in the `~/.aws/credentials` file.

And serverless is picking the default credentials.

So, I kept the new credentials under `[default]` and removed the previous credentials. And that worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Hope these credentials are fake, As for the good practice we should not share aws secretes to any one

Comment: They stole my credentials once by my mistake... They used it to mine crypto and I got billed 75K USD a day... Luckely for me AWS saved me with it <3

Answer (score 0):

to run the function from AWS you need to configure AWS with access_key_id and secret_access_key
but
to might get this error if you want to run the function locally
so for that use this command

```
sls invoke local -f functionName
```

it will run the function locally not on aws

Answer (score 0):

If none of these answers work, it's maybe because you need to add a `provider` in your serverless account and add your AWS keys.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your credentials on ~/.aws/credentials file are fine.
Delete line on your .yml config file

region: us-east-1

and try again